# How to display a div block only on the main page on Datalife Engine?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, datalife-engine

I have a div block that I only want to display on the first page. I mean, if the user is on

```
http://mywebsite.com/
```

it displays the div. But if he navigates to the second page of the posts

```
http://mywebsite.com/page/2
```

it hides that div. I am using Datalife Engine.

Div example:

```
<div class="example"> This is a test </div>
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You say you're using Datalife, right? That wouldn't happen to have anything to do with www2.datalife.com, would it?

Comment: @MrLister nah. It's a russian plataform. :) I don't have any HTML files. Template files are .TPL and .CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For datalife engine, display just on the first page we use:

```
[page-count=1]Content goes here[/page-count]
```

Answer (score 1):

follow this and all be worked fine.

```
  <head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){


        if( $('#mainPage').length > 0 ) {

           $("#hideMe").css({"display": "block"});

        } else {

           $("#hideMe").css({"display": "none"});

        }


      });//end doc ready function 


  </script>


  </head>

  <body>

     <div id="mainPage">  </div>


      <div id="hideMe">lorem ipsum</div>

  </body>
```

hope it helps you

example http://jsfiddle.net/viktorino/56ea5/

Comment: I php files on datalife engine are a litle bit diferent. :)

I am not using wordpress

Comment: this use is not only in wordpress.  you can use it where you want

Comment: But my "looks" are defined by tpl files, not php. I have my div on tpl files :)

Comment: then do this with jquery. check on what page you and if it main page  set the div with display block

Comment: Sorry, can you help with the jquery code? Don't know much about it :P

Comment: i change my unswer check it

Comment: Hmm, or i'm using it wrong or it's not working. This is what i've done http://jsfiddle.net/B6AZ3/

I only changed displayed the js in the js tags on the template files. It doesn't do nothing when changing pages.

Comment: `$("#Myblock")` not `$("Myblock")`

Comment: an dont forget load jquery library 2.1.0 it is work i checked it . if it help you mark my answer . change id  of your navigation div in html and you see that div is hide.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  And as i've said before, i don't have HTML files...i've included Jquery library and tried...

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: look up on my answer. i have made changes. that you can understand it now

Comment: What is suposed the "$('#mainPage').length" measure? I'm still missing something. Or it hides everytime or it shows everytime depending on the ID i put in there. content is called with {content} tag on the template files(.tpl files). just this. I could send you the link maybe. I can't start a chat :S

Comment: my english not so good but i try excplane you `$('#mainPage').length` measure is that exists. if is exists the length is 1 and when it's not the length is 0. mark up my answer with code. it is important to me. you need to put your div with content that you want to hide on both of pages with display:none; in css as default and then on main page put my code of answer. with your selectors.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is, that i don't want to know if exists or not. What i mean is, you go to the mainpage, you navigate to the 2º page on the navbar... Since there's allways a post there, it will allways be 1...

Comment: you want to display this div only on main page. you don't need to now if he exist or not. he exists allways ,you just hide him on both of pages with the code that i write you.

Comment: Viktorino, that's the problem. I want that to show on the mainpage, but just the page number 1! If i go to page number two, it hides the content. I don't want to display in one page and hide on other, that's not the problem